# Cannot call fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I have followed the script to make navigation drawer from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/), but i get an error.

```
 private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        //aaa
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

the error is in this code:

```
fragment = new HomeFragment();
```

it say "Type mismatch: cannot convert from HomeFragment to Fragment"

FYI, i use 
`import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;`

but when i convert it to

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

the error are on this line

```
`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`
```

when i change activity to FragmentActivity, there is no error, but i can't open my Sliding menu...

anyone can help me?? sorry for my english.. :D

Comment: Are you using fragments below api level 11? Also What is the inport for fragment in  `HomeFragment`?

Comment: sorry, it has been solved now... but i still got a problem, when i click the upper left sliding menu, it cant show up, but if i slide from left to right it will show, can i show the sliding menu just by click it??